# Push button to only turn off circuit

Tags: transistors, switching

First off I have no background in electronics but have been coding since decades and have successfully built things around an STM32 blue pill.

Now I am trying to build a battery powered circuit which should have a push button to turn it off. Once the circuit is off, another push of the same button should NOT turn it back on (turning it on it will be done by monitoring voltage of a separate circuit). I have found tons of latching circuits but all of them incorporate the turning back on feature which I explicitly do not want. Is there an easy way to do this (without using an MCU)?

Comment: How do you want it to be turned on again? That well effect how you turn it off... But you could just use a push switch to tell the processor to turn itself off, which then turns off the driving FET. Pushing the button again will have no effect as the MCU is powered off.

Comment: It will be auto-powered on as soon as a different circuit is turned off, trying to build a battery backup circuit. As said I would like to build it without an MCU.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTN9az.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use the CMOS NAND, because the NAND4 output will rise completely up to VDD, which places ZERO volts on the base-emitter junction of the transistor, to ensure the transistor is OFF.

How much current can this switch provide?  Depends on the current thru R2. 
And the current thru R2 depends on how close to Ground the output of NAND4 will go. Assume that output is not at 0volts, but at 0.4 volts. That places about  (5v - Veb - 0.4v ) or (5v - 0.6 - 0.4) = 4 volts across R2. Using Ohms Law, we have 4 milliAmps thru R2, and to achieve a well-saturated transistor you should keep the steady-state current below 10X that, or 40 milliAmps.

During turnon, you will be charging bypass capacitors in your circuit, and 100s of milliAmps will be flowing into the zero-voltage-initial capacitors. 
This "charging interval" will last microseconds or milliSeconds, as the bypass capacitors ramp up to about (5v - 0.2v) = 4.8 volts.

Is 4.8 volts (at 40 milliamp DC demand) adequate?

===========================================

When "unswitched power" initially rises,  the status of this latch will be uncertain because we do not know how the "external momentary low" behaves. The pullup of R1 is ideal, in that the "high" input will not alter LatchOut state. If "external momentary low" can become and remain LOW as Unswitched Power rises, then the Switched Power will be turned ON even as Unswitched Power ramps up.

You need to decide what behavior is needed. PowerOnReset circuits can be complex. Draw a block-diagram of your system: battery, stepup regulator, this switch, and your various loads and the currents needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! What electronic part would be a good one to use for the two NAND gates? Switched power will be running 5V, max of 1A.

Comment: 74HC00. But add the buffering, per changes in the schematic

Comment: Again many thanks for your help. I am afraid I do not fully understand how the schematic works, but I was planning on having approx 5V 1A draw on the switched power, it might be way less though, I would need to check. Unswitched power is stepped-up (to 5V) one cell Lithium-Polymer battery, (3.7V nominal, 4.2V at full charge)

Comment: For clarity, draw your expected system schematic, including the battery source, the stepup regulator, this push-button-to-turn-off switch, and all your loads. Use boxes for each part of the system, and show grounds and power and the control signals and the loads; big difference between 0.04 amps and  1.0 amps. If load current is much above 0.04 amps, we'll need a much bigger transistor switch to ensure the switched-VDD will remain very close to 5.0 volts.

Comment: I will do this as soon as possible, please give me a week or two. I'll for sure get back to this as I really want to get this thing up and running.